# Odoo 13 - How to Add New Column in Sales Order Lines tab

Tags: odoo-13

How to Add new field in Sales Order lines Tab in Odoo 13?

My Goal is to add new field/column before Product column in Sales Order Line tab.

Answer (score 4):

res_sale_order_line.py

```
class ResSaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order.line"

    new_field = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='New Field')
```

views.xml

```
<xpath expr="//page[@name='order_lines']/field[@name='order_line']/form/group/group/field[@name='product_id']" position="before"> <field name="new_field"/> </xpath>

<xpath expr="//page[@name='order_lines']/field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='product_id']" position="before"> <field name="new_field"/> </xpath>
```

[image]